# Combining rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with 18 columns and about 10000 rows.

My first 3 columns have separate values for `YEAR`, `MONTH`, and `DAY`. I need to merge these three columns and have the entire date in one column for all the rows.

My code so far is:

```
df.merge('Year','/','Month')
```

Comment: What is a DataFrame? Please show us some code so we can understand what you are doing.

Comment: its a pandas DataFrame im sure ... pandas being a numpy wrapper with added functionality .... (its probably classified as more than a wrapper)

Comment: temp = read_table(folder + r'\BBE_12-11-13_0731_edited_2.lvm',
 sep=r'\t')

cols = ['Year',
        'Month',
        'Day',
        'Hour'
        'Minute',
        'Seconde',
        'Depth (m)',
        'Temperature (Deg C)',
        'Green (µg_l)',
        'Blue_Green (µg_l)',
        'Diatom (µg_l)',
        'Crypto (µg_l)',
        'Class5 (µg_l)',
        'Class6 (µg_l)',
        'Class7 (µg_l)',
        'Yellow (µg_l)',
        'Transmission (%)']
        
        
df = DataFrame(data = temp)

df.columns = cols

Comment: Have Reposted the Question....Please Check below link/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757490/merge-columns-using-python-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @RahulBhatia Why did you repost the question, instead of editing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) *([`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) is like a database join.):*

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [2]: df = DataFrame([[1,11,2012],[1,10,2012]], columns=['day','month','year'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   day month  year
0    1    11  2012
1    1    10  2012

In [4]: df.apply(lambda row: str(row['day'])+'/'+str(row['month'])+'/'+str(row['year']), axis=1)
Out[4]: 
0    1/11/2012
1    1/10/2012
```

*The `axis=1` part means you are selecting columns rather than row.*

If you wanted to give a specific date you could use datetime:

```
In [5]: import datetime

In [6]: df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime(row['year'],row['month'],row['day']), axis=1)
Out[6]: 
0    2012-11-01 00:00:00
1    2012-10-01 00:00:00
```

You can add these as columns in you dataframe as follows:

```
In [7]: df['new_date'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row['day'])+'/'+str(row['month'])+'/'+str(row['year']), axis=1)

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   day month  year   new_date
0    1    11  2012  1/11/2012
1    1    10  2012  1/10/2012
```

.

*It's worth noting that pandas has an easy way to [`parse_dates` when reading as a csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).*